# Separate names with initials from a string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have been trying to separate names from a sentence, but I am failing to do so with regular expression (which I am new to)
I used the following `names = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',string)`

But it gives an output like `['John', 'H', 'Watson', 'Sir', 'Arthur', 'Ignatius', 'Conan', 'Doyle']`, I was trying to get it like `['John H. Watson', 'Sir Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle']`

***code:***

```
string = "John H. Watson is not real but Sir Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle is"
names = re.findall(r'[A-Z][a-z]*',string)
print names
```

**response:**

```
['John', 'H', 'Watson', 'Sir', 'Arthur', 'Ignatius', 'Conan', 'Doyle']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relook at your regex and you'll see that it will match any word that starts with a capital and a separate match. I suppose you want to do something more like:

```
(?:\s?\b[A-Z][a-z\.]*)+
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/2eQsAPJ79jXjm73s)

This will repeat match until a 'non-name' comes up (ie, a word that isnt capitalized).

The problem is that there are obviously going to be cases where this will match non-names. One that I can think of is if a sentence starts with a non-name and the second word IS a name, it will include that first word will be included in the match. For example, 'The Sir Arthur' will include `The`. the GOOD things about this regex is that names like `McDonald` can be matched by taking away the `\b` token.

Answer (score 2):

For your example this regex will work:

```
>>> print re.findall(ur'(?:\b[A-Z][a-z]*\W+)*[A-Z][a-z]*\b', string)
['John H. Watson', 'Sir Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle']
```

However names can be really complex with many edge cases.

Comment: Yes `Hi,John H. Watson is not real but Sir Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle is good I really like him` generates `['Hi,John H. Watson', 'Sir Arthur Ignatius Conan Doyle', 'I']`

Comment: For example (excerpt)  names from `Hello my name is Chandler Muriel Bing. I have a friend who is named Pieter van den Woude and he has another friend, A. A. Milne. Gandalf the Gray joins us. Together, we make up the Friends Cast and Crew`

Comment: What is your expected output from above input?

Comment: Full names from the text- Thanks

Comment: I suggest you edit your question provide these examples with your **expected match** as you have one at present in question. Comments are not the right place for this.

Comment: I really liked the code but it was not working in python3 i guess the syntax might have changed in python3. Altough it was a very small change and i was able to run the code.

`print(re.findall(r'(?:\b[A-Z][a-z]*\W+)*[A-Z][a-z]*\b', string))`